# getting access to the SharePoint List that kicked off a workflow

Tags: sharepoint, workflow

I've been told that I need to reference the SPWorkflow ParentItem. I'm not sure on the syntax though. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.workflow.spworkflowactivationproperties.list.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you're inside the workflow itself then your workflow will have a "workflowProperties" object and will be of the type referenced in zincorp's answer.

You'll need to get its .List property or .ListUrl or even .ListId and then you'll be able to get at the SPList.